# Possible to code fold classNames in IntelliJ automatically?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm, classname

To make my IDE coding platform cleaner and easier to read, I was wondering if it's possible to hide/code fold the classNames while coding in react.

For example:

```
<div className='classname1 classname2 classname3'>text</div>`
```

to

```
<div className'...'>Text</div>
```

Anyone know if this is possible or where to look? Using WebStorm specifically.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/folding-code-elements.html#specifying_prefs

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box, but you can write a plugin to do that for you.

Comment: Agreed, I was unsuccessful at finding a solution aside from making it myself. Thank you @Yole

Comment: there is no such feature; please feel free to file a request for it to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB